# GL2 -> profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Graphic card: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics (HSW GT1)
Processing 4.0b9 give this error:

```
java.lang.InternalError: XXX0 profile[2]: GL2 -> profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.computeProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2098)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1976)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1895)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1861)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:80)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:239)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:225)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2324)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1009)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getGL2ES2(GLProfile.java:930)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initGL(PSurfaceJOGL.java:215)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initFrame(PSurfaceJOGL.java:149)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10537)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10443)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10187)
    at MPUTeapot.main(MPUTeapot.java:210)
X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 1/1, reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 1)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 1
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7f61f80019d0, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
```

Answer (score -2):

Ciao,
I've run:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken
```

Then

```
sudo apt update
```

And then everything worked again.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't explain in what way updating your system installation helped resolve the problem. Please consider editing your post to add more explanation, in particular which OS distribution and version it applies to, which software packages in what version were broken, and what version they have been updated to that made the system run properly again.